# Specialization error: confilct between template member function and overloaded non-template function

Tags: c++

I want to put two different methods in a template class, one should be a function template, the other a non-template function with the same name. Here is a toy model of the code which does not compile under gcc, but does under Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <int N>
    T f (T x)
    {
        return N*x;
    }
    T f (T x)
    {
        return f<15>(x);
    }
};

template <>
template <int N>
double A<double>:: f(double x)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double x=3;
    A<double> a;
    std::cout<<a.f<2>(x)<<" "<<a.f(x)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is "ambiguous template specialization" and obviously disappears when I give to the functions different names. Problem is, I need f to denote both the templated function and the non-template one, for compatibility reason. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Why the specialization for double that return 0?  do you want this to print 0 0, or 6 45?

Comment: Actually, it is a simple toy model of the code I need, I just put there something to check the behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You can add a default template parameter and remove the second overload.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <int N = 15>
    T f (T x)
    {
        return N*x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I had already tried this but in this way I lose compatibility with my version of Visual Studio, which allows default template arguments only on class templates. I need compliance with both, unfortunately, is there another possible workaround?

Comment: @Amaicch I can't think of any solution without a default template argument, sorry...